# PHP - curl not calling index.php page by default

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to get data from http://my_example_domain.com

Now just curious about - why I am not getting data of index.php page by default.

My Command line is -

```
curl 'http://my_example_domain.com'
```

Note - I am getting data if I put slash at the end -

```
curl 'http://my_example_domain.com/'
```

Comment: This could be due to the way the web server is configured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web server is not configured to display index.php as the default index document. In Apache this is configured by adding:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

To your VirtualHost or Directory config entry:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ...
</Directory>
```